# Blocking the incoming request even after promisify

Tags: node.js

I am having an express get method which in turn makes a HTTP request to Git Api. I am invoking GIT API using Http module and calling it inside the promisify method. I am getting the proper output. But still, when I invoke the API from two different browser tabs I am seeing the request executed synchronously. I understood that http get will be getting in to the event loop queue but even the console which is in entry point is not getting printed.

_expressApp.get("/git",GitHubService.FetchUser)

```
public static  FetchUser(req:Request, resp:Response,Next:NextFunction)
{
     console.log("Going to fetch11");
     GitHubService.FetchGitData().then((data)=>
    {
        console.log("data");
        resp.send(data);

     }).catch((error)=>
    {
        resp.send(error);
    })
    .finally(()=>
    {
        resp.end();
    })

}

private static FetchGitData() : any
{
    return  new Promise((resolve,reject)=>
    {
        console.log("Going to fetch");
        let data ='';
    https.get('https://api.github.com/users/ccrkhere',{headers: {'user-agent': 'node.js','Content-Type': 'application/json'}},  (_resp:any) => {
    _resp.on("error",(err)=>{
        console.log("Data");
                  reject(err);
    })

    _resp.on("data",(chunk)=>
    {
        data = data + chunk;

    })

    _resp.on("end",()=>
    {
        sleep(10000);
        console.log("Data");
        resolve(data);
   })

    })
     });


}
```

Actual result when invoked in two browser tabs

Going to fetch 1
Going to fetch

Going to fetch 1
Going to fetch

Expected

Going to fetch 1
Going to fetch 1
Going to fetch
Going to fetch

Node js has default two thread pools so when two requests is made the task will be assigned to two thread pool which will parallel continue executing the task. In that case, won't that log the first console statement is my question is.

Comment: Sorry that I forgot to add a point.

Comment: `Node js has default two thread pools` - yes but one is exclusively for disk I/O, everything else uses the main thread. So all network requests run on a single thread. They can still be parallel because they are async I/O. The OS (Linux, Mac, Windows, BSD, Solaris etc.) implement async I/O using the same mechanism as threads - the OS event queue. So async I/O are not implemented on top of threads. Instead both async I/O (single threaded node.js) and threads are implemented on top of OS event queue

Comment: Actually, node.js runs five threads (4 threads + the main thread) - one for disk I/O, one for cryptography, one for DNS and one for zip (compression, but generally only zip) -- https://nodejs.org/ru/docs/guides/dont-block-the-event-loop/

Answer (score 0):

Your code is entirely synchronous up to the point where you call `https.get()` so that's why you see this:

```
Going to fetch 1 
Going to fetch
```

from the first request before you see anything else.  Then, once you fire that first asynchronous `https.get()` and return from that, then the next incoming request gets pulled form the event queue and it can start to process and then you get this:

```
Going to fetch 1 
Going to fetch
```

from the second request.

---

Keep in mind that a promise is just a notification system.  It just notifies registered listeners when some actual asynchronous operation  is done.  It doesn't magically make anything asynchronous.  Just because you go inside a `new Promise()` constructor, that doesn't make anything asynchronous.  In fact, the promise executor is called synchronously.  It's only when you start some actual asynchronous operation and then return from starting that, that node.js can go back to the event loop and fetch the next event from the event queue and process it.

---

Also, please remove the `sleep(10000)` as that type of logic never belongs in a node.js server meant to handle multiple requests/users.  I don't why you have it there, but there's always a better way to solve whatever problem you're trying to solve (probably with `setTimeout()`) that doesn't block the whole server.

---

> Node js has default two thread pools so when two requests is made the task will be assigned to two thread pool which will parallel continue executing the task. In that case, won't that log the first console statement is my question is.

I don't know where you got this notion from, but this is not how node.js works.  It has ONE thread for running your Javascript.  It uses a thread pool for some internal asynchronous operations such as file I/O, but that thread pool isn't used for running your Javascript.  node.js runs your Javascript single threaded.  There is no parallel running of two Javascript threads each running an incoming request when you just have one node.js process.

If you want multiple threads of Javascript, you have to program it specifically that way with Worker Threads, Clustering or separate node.js processes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed explanation. Actual result what I got is Going to Fetch 1, Going to fetch, Data, data and then Going to fetch 1, going to fetch, Data, data. Am I missing anything so when the event-loop picks the second request it should start print going to fetch1 and going to fetch before the data which is in end of first request. Yes I wrote thread to make the end to complete in delay.

Comment: @user2736031 - Did this answer your question?  If so, you can indicate that to the community here by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points here on stackoverflow for following the proper procedure.  If this didn't answer your question, please comment about which part of your question you're still confused about.

Answer (score 0):

Yes after blogging through many sites I understood that Promises or async / await get processed parallelly. We can use an async-await function to complete our task quickly as much as possible.

https://www.quora.com/Does-Express-js-handle-multiple-connections-at-once-Geek-explainations-are-welcome